# NumLock turns off after login?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, 16.10

Hi  My NumLock is turned on during Grub2 and Login, but as soon as my password is verified it is automatically turned off.
This happens during loading of my profile on my Toshiba laptop after clean install (on a new SSD disk), so where does this annoying setting hide?
Please how can I get my Xubuntu to leave my NumLock alone?

Well after a couple of upgrades Xubuntu have finally decided to leave my numlock the way I like it (turned on), what happened is still a mystery to me!!

So I will accept silokos answer - for the effort..

```
       Happy Ubunting   ;-)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [this](http://code23.info/enable-numlock-at-boot-time-with-lightdm-xubuntu-16-04/) article you need to install a helpder utility and ensure it runs after logging on:

```
sudo aptitude install numlockx    # Install numlockx
sudo vim /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/99-numlockx.conf    # Create this a config file for lightdm to start numlock at boot
```

and enter

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

Comment: According to the LightDM docs (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM) the greeter-setup-script key invokes the command when the X servers and user sessions start. This happens after the login screen is shown. I haven't tested it though.

Comment: numlockx is a binary which controls the state of numlock. It can be run whenever you like.  numlockx on, numlockx off can be invoked at any time.

Comment: Ok thanks, so by installing numlockx we can turn it back on any time!  But what turns it off during user settings??